# SQLPlus Connection Issue when using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, sqlplus

Trying to connect to ORACLE SQLPLUS using unix shell script. But it is getting failed..
Looks like the script in line 3 is incorrect as I am passing username, password and SID

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /dev/shrd/alt/test1/stest/ptest
V1=`sqlplus testuser/passwd@testSID <<EOF
SELECT count(*) FROM test_table WHERE region='Aus';
EXIT;
EOF`
if [ -z "$V1" ]; then
  echo "No rows returned"
  exit 0
else
  echo $V1
fi
```

I got an error stating -ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified when I added - `sqlplus $username/$password` in the script.

Can anyone please confirm if the below syntax is valid and I can add it in shell script?

```
   > sqlplus MyUsername/MyPassword@MyHostname:1521/MyServiceName
```

Kindly guide me if I'm missing something (like Hostname, Port Number,TNS_entry or something else).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: First remove the `-S` option to get a better response and error message. In general the syntax look OK.

Comment: You have a missing closing backquote when calculating  `V1`. Note also that command substitution using backquotes is deprecated. Also I don't understand why the question is tagged bash; how are you invoking this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you are **successful** in obtaining any output from your sqlplus command, *you should **not** use "-S"*.  Without that, sqlplus will provide you with much-needed error-reporting/feedback to debug your command interface/call.

Also, as per [**this**](http://www.dbatoolz.com/t/sqlplus-s-shell-scripting.html), it is inadvisable to provide the password on that command line.  For that reason, the service/DB administrators **probably disallow that form of accessing** the service/DB/